# Qt Qt3d Example Project Monkeygod in Linux works, but Windows doesn' t work

Tags: c++, windows, qt, qt3d

I have compiled Qt3d for Linux Mint and also for Windows. Everything worked OK in Linux.
All Example Project are working, but in Example Project Monkeygod (Windows) i can only see a cube and an errormessage:

```
Could not load file:///C:/Users/Michael/git/build-qt3d-Desktop_Qt_5_2_0_MinGW_32bit-Release/bin/resources/examples/monkeygod/qml/meshes/penguin.3ds (possibly plugin could not be found)
Asset importer error: Chunk is too large

Could not load file:///C:/Users/Michael/git/build-qt3d-Desktop_Qt_5_2_0_MinGW_32bit-Release/bin/resources/examples/monkeygod/qml/meshes/penguin.3ds (possibly plugin could not be found)
No scene object with ID:  0 for QQuickMesh(0x51ff40) 
No scene object with ID:  0 for QQuickMesh(0x51d900) 
No scene object with ID:  0 for QQuickMesh(0x51dd78) 
No scene object with ID:  0 for QQuickMesh(0x4f9620)
```

What is the meaning of that ?
Please help,
lg 
Michael

Comment: Same problem here. Trying to figure it out.

Comment: Seems like an Assimp problem where your model is somehow too large. Try loading a .dae model.